# Dockerfile entrypoint binary set to an env variable

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a builder script to create a Docker image.  In that builder script I have passed on the binary name as build-args.

However when i use it in entrypoint as: `Entrypoint["./"${pkg}]`, it does resolve `pkg` the Docker container fails to run stating "./rtspappserver not found".

Here `rtspappserver` is the `pkg` name. The build args I sent from script were set as ENV vars in the Dockerfile.

Below is Dockerfile for reference:

```sh
#Download base image ubuntu 18.04
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ARG package_name
ENV TZ=Etc/UTC
ENV pkg=$package_name
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone
# Update and dist-upgrade ubuntu
RUN apt update -y && \
    apt dist-upgrade -y && \
    apt install -y python-heatclient
WORKDIR /
COPY ${pkg} /
ENTRYPOINT ["./rtspappserver"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an option I wouldn't tend to pass as a build-arg.  My general experience has been that, if you do have an environment that produces multiple binaries or commands, the largest part of the image (both by image size and Dockerfile complexity) is code that's shared across all of the commands, so building a separate image per command can be overkill.

You can specify an alternate command to run as the part of the `docker run` command after the image name, or in a `command:` line in a `docker-compose.yml` file.  Then you can copy everything into the image, specifying some default command

```sh
FROM ubuntu:18.04
...
WORKDIR /app  # try to avoid dropping things in /
ENV PATH /app:$PATH
COPY . .
CMD mainserver
```

Now if you just `docker run the_image` it will run `mainserver`, but instead you can

```
docker run ... the_image rtspappserver
```

to run an alternate command.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood the question correctly, but this might help: You can specify the `ENTRYPOINT` in either 'shell' or 'exec' form. You currently use the latter, which does not interpolate environment variables.

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example):

> You can specify a plain string for the ENTRYPOINT and it will execute in /bin/sh -c. This form will use shell processing to substitute shell environment variables [...]

Comment: Note that if you do use a plain string for `ENTRYPOINT` it will effectively prevent you from getting access to the `CMD`.